# What function changes do i need to do in order to get the required Figure

Tags: c++, glut, freeglut

Move the given figure to **13 more figures** in the **second and third** quadrants with one function (**6 in the second and 7 in the third**), so that the displacement of two adjacent figures in the same quadrant is **2 units on the x-axis** and **3 units on the y axis**. Auxiliary axes to be from one unit. Adjust the viewport view as well. The first basic figure from which the others start should be square in shape with one unit and centered at the beginning of the coordinate system.

**Heres how the figure looks  when the code is compiled:**

[image: The Compiled Code]

**Here is the Code:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
GLint   N=6;
GLfloat x=12.0;
void boshtet(void)
{
    int i;
    glColor3f(.9, .04, .70); 
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(i=0; i<=N; i++) {
        glVertex2f(-x+2.0*i*x/N, -x);
        glVertex2f(-x+2.0*i*x/N, x);
        glVertex2f(-x, -x+2.0*i*x/N);
        glVertex2f(x, -x+2.0*i*x/N);
    }
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(.25, .25, .25); 
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(0, -x);
        glVertex2f(0, x);
        glVertex2f(-x, 0);
        glVertex2f(x, 0);
    glEnd();
}
void vizatimi(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    
    glVertex3f(0., 0., 0.);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.);
    glVertex3f(1., 0., 0.);
    glVertex3f(1., 0.5, 0.);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0., 0.5, 0.);
    glEnd();
}
void myDisplay(void) 
{
    int j=1;
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    boshtet();
    glColor3f(.25, .25, .12); 
    vizatimi();
    glColor3f(.98, .625, .12); 
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)  
    {
       glLoadIdentity();
       glTranslatef(2.0+2*j,1.0+j,0.0); 
       vizatimi();
    } 
    glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
void myReshape(int lart, int gjer)
{
    glClearColor (.75, .75, .75, 0.0);
    glViewport(0,0,lart,gjer);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-x, x, -x, x, -x, x);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("ushtrimi4");
    glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay); 
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: All I see is an assignement. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried some code combinations but they are not giving the results required to solve the problem.

Comment: You should explicitly share your efforts, else the question might get closed because of SO rules.